# when I try to console.log(window.x) i am getting undefind? where x is not in program never existed

Tags: javascript, variables, console, window

console.log(window.x) // answer is undefind
console.log(x)  // ans is reference error saying that x is not defind

When I try to console.log(x) where x is never existed in code, it gives me reference error as x is not defined so x will not take any memory, but when i console.log(window.x) is giving undefined and taking space of undefined why so?

Comment: an undefined *property* doesn't "take space"